# xserver terminates with segmentation fault error every time after hit a touchscreen

Tags: 12.04, touchscreen, xserver

I have ubuntu 12.04 installed on apalis nvidia Tegra T30 with lxde desktop environment and xserver version:

```
 X.Org X Server 1.11.3
Release Date: 2011-12-16
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux 2.6.38-1209-omap4 armv7l Ubuntu
Current Operating System: Linux tegra-ubuntu 3.1.10-g34c5824 #3 SMP PREEMPT Tue Jul 26 11:10:58 CEST 2016 armv7l
Kernel command line: core_edp_mv=1300 usb_high_speed=1 ip=off root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rw,noatime rootfstype=ext3 rootwait igb_mac=00:14:2d:28:72:82 consoleblank=0 no_console_suspend=1 console=tty1 console=tty0
Build Date: 05 April 2012  12:04:28AM
xorg-server 2:1.11.4-0ubuntu10 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
Current version of pixman: 0.24.4
        Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
        to make sure that you have the latest version.
```

I have added touschscreen configuration to xorg.conf as bellow:

```
    Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "evdev touchscreen catchall"
        MatchProduct "IR1210AZX-LeadingTouch"
        Driver "evdev"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
EndSection
```

The problem which I`m facing is that xserver crashes every time just after a single touch a touchscreen with error:

```
        [    40.147] BUG: triggered 'if (!b || !v)'
    BUG: ../../Xi/exevents.c:991 in UpdateDeviceState()
    [    40.148]
    Backtrace:
    [    40.148] BUG: triggered 'if (!b || !v)'
    BUG: ../../Xi/exevents.c:991 in UpdateDeviceState()
    [    40.148]
    Backtrace:
    [    40.650] BUG: triggered 'if (!b || !v)'
    BUG: ../../Xi/exevents.c:1004 in UpdateDeviceState()
    [    40.650]
    Backtrace:
    [    40.651] BUG: triggered 'if (!b || !v)'
    BUG: ../../Xi/exevents.c:1004 in UpdateDeviceState()
    [    40.651]
    Backtrace:
    [    40.651]
[    40.651] BUG: triggered 'if (!b || !v)'
BUG: ../../Xi/exevents.c:1004 in UpdateDeviceState()
[    40.651]
Backtrace:
[    40.651]
Backtrace:
[    40.651] Segmentation fault at address 0x5
[    40.651]
Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault). Server aborting
[    40.651]
```

Do you have any ideas how to resolve this problem? BTW I cannot upgrade dist to newer ubuntu because I have to use specific kernel with graphic nvidia driver and this kernel do not support newer ABI.